# Fix gridster container

Tags: angular6, frontend, angular-gridster2

I'm using angular-gridster2 in my angular 6 application. When ever I drag a grid, it is going beyond the container. I want to restrict the grid in moving out of my container.

I have tried giving gridType: 'fit'. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `gridType: GridType.Fixed`

And set `maxCols` and `maxRows` options to grid cols and grid rows value.

```
this.options.maxCols = this.gridster.gridColumns.length;
this.options.maxRows = this.gridster.gridRows.length;
```

It is worked in my side.